# Swift button action selector when touched from another class: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, button

In a UIViewController (my BaseViewController below), I am adding a subview of a popup dialog view (from another class NotifDialog) containing a button.

This button should hide the popup dialog when touched.

My problem is that either the button doesn't detect touch or throws "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
class NotifDialog: NSObject {
    var dialogView: UIView!

    superView = controller.view
    dialogView = UIView()        

    superView?.addSubview(dialogView)
    dialogView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let dialogViewWidth = BaseViewController.screenWidth * 0.66
    let dialogViewHeight = BaseViewController.screenHeight * 0.45

    dialogView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superView?.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor)!).isActive = true
    dialogView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (superView?.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor)!).isActive = true
    dialogView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dialogViewWidth).isActive = true
    dialogView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dialogViewHeight).isActive = true        

    let bClose = UIButton()

    dialogView?.addSubview(bClose)

    bClose.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let bCloseWidth = dialogViewWidth * 0.5

    bClose.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dialogView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    bClose.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dialogView.topAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    bClose.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bCloseWidth).isActive = true
    bClose.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

    //bClose.addTarget(controller, action:#selector(self.hide(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) -> touch not detected
    //bClose.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.closeDialog(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) -> throws error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

}

func closeDialog(_ sender : UIButton) {
    dialogView.isHidden = true
}
```

.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let topViewController :UIViewController = self.navigationController!.topViewController!
    let dialog = NotifDialog()
    dialog.loadCustomViewIntoController(controller: topViewController)
}
```

Setting my button the following way makes it like touch is not detected

```
bClose.addTarget(self, action:#selector(closeDialog(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Setting my button the following way detects touches, but throws error : "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
bClose.addTarget(controller, action:#selector(closeDialog(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Finally, I also tried to make my function closeDialog static. In this case it doesn't crash anymore, however I can't use dialogView in it since this var is not static.

How can I hide my dialog from this button's touch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `closeDialog` message is sent to the target you specified in the `addTarget` call. Since the `closeDialog` method exists on the NotifDialog class, you need to make the NotifDialog instance the target.

```
bClose.addTarget(
    dialog, // This is the instance that will receive the message
    action:#selector(closeDialog(_:)),
    for: .touchUpInside
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rengers. I am familiar with creating an instance of class B inside class A, but I don't really know how to create an instance of class A inside class A. Sorry if that doesn't make sense

Comment: The problem could be that the instance of NotifDialog gets released from memory when `viewDidLoad` returns. Try to make `dialog` an instance variable on `BaseViewController`.

Comment: This is already the case, I am creating an instance of NotifDialog inside BaseViewController.

Comment: Yes, but you are not assigning it to an instance variable. The `dialog` variable is scoped to the `viewDidLoad` method, and will be released from memory when that method returns.

Comment: indeed! Assigning a NotifDialog instance as class var of BaseViewController finally works as intended, while it was not working as a temp var. Thank you @Rengers